# Removing the header in Powershell Export-Csv output for Select-Object

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, get-aduser

I'm outputting a list of members from an AD group to a csv file. Right now it's outputting with the header 'name'. I currently want to have the output without the header.

This is my code:

```
$groupNames = @('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4')

foreach ($group in $groupNames) {
    $csvPath = "$group.csv"
    $groupdn = (Get-ADGroup $group).DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof=$groupdn)" |
        Select-Object name |
        Export-Csv -Path $csvPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Current Output:

```
name
clark kent
mickey mouse
jolly rancher
```

Desired Output:

```
clark kent
mickey mouse
jolly rancher
```

I've tried replacing `Select-Object -Property name` with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty name` but it does not give the desired output found in other answers on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is no longer a Csv but a plain text file with a list of AD object names thus `Export-Csv` is no longer the right cmdlet for your use case, you should change it to `Set-Content` and expand the objects `.Name` attribute instead of *selecting* them:

```bash
$groupNames = @('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4')

foreach ($group in $groupNames) {
    $csvPath = "$group.csv"
    $groupdn = (Get-ADGroup $group).DistinguishedName
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(memberof=$groupdn)" |
        ForEach-Object name |
        Set-Content $plainTextPath
}
```